# Is it possible to improve a bad question to aid in a question ban?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, post-ban, quality-improvement

I have [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65708019/is-it-possible-to-have-more-than-15-decimal-digits-in-a-float-without-decimal-mo). As of the writing of this question, it has a score of -2. I've edited it a few times to try and bring up the score, to try and get out of my question ban. It seems that it's just generally a bad question*, so is it even possible to get improve it in a way that it gets upvoted?

I'm looking for any suggestions on what improvements can be made to the question.

* I think it's a good question to be honest.

Comment: It is possible. And if successful it will help you towards getting out of the question ban.

Comment: Well, I've been unsuccessful. Can you give me some pointers?

Comment: Ehhh, not really. Looks like you've done what you can. Some posts just don't end up upvoted. Maybe you'll get lucky and someone reading this post will upvote it. Maybe you won't. My advice would be to take your time when you can next ask a question (a question ban is more of a rate limiter, not a hard ban, you will be able to ask again). And make sure your next question is a good one (which is admittedly difficult).

Comment: I've been question banned for ages now, I think it might be hard.

Comment: "I think it's a good question to be honest." - are you judging that from a satellite view (because if you zoom out far enough then you get into "there are no bad questions" territory)... or are you judging that from the list of rules and guidelines that Stack Overflow has set? Big difference. Yeah the question doesn't look bad (although large bold NOTE blocks... not a fan) in general, for the generic internet arena where Reddit and Quora also exist. But is it useful in the context of Stack Overflow? MisterMiyagi's answer seems to hint towards "no".

Comment: @Gimby What do you recommend I replace the note with?

Comment: @CATboardBETA - it takes more than just one bad question to be question banned.  So how about fixing your other questions that were not well received? You should focus on getting your deleted questions undeleted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me that the underlying problem is that the question is not-good due to multiple (possible) misunderstandings. This makes it hard to answer in a generally useful way, because every future reader will see it with their own set of (possible) misunderstandings. Removing these issues may be difficult without changing the gist of the question.

You might be able to salvage the bulk of the question by *acknowledging*/*removing* these misunderstandings if they are not relevant or by *clearly defining* expectations.

- `float` does not store digits-after-`.`, and especially not *decimal* digits. It is *very* common for people to muddle literals, representations, and values of numeric types – showing confusion about the core of the question does not inspire confidence that an answer will be understood.

  - => Providing *some* background (1-2 sentences should be enough) can help ground the question in reality instead of confusion.
- A number with 494 (!!!) decimal digits is inappropriate to *minimally* represent the case of 15 decimal digits. This makes it entirely unclear whether the question makes the sensible request to have ~20 digits or the ludicrous request to have ~500 digits.

  - => Reduce the number to a *realistic* example.
  - => Provide an edge case as well. For example, a number with less than 15 decimal digits – should it appear as short as possible, or padded with zeroes?
  - => The `dict` is a pointless complication. Remove it.

- The *representation* of a `float` is different from its *value*. By using `print` the questions tests the *representation*, while the text so far seemed to be about the *value*.

  - => Clearly define what the desired behaviour is *in practice*. This may very well be `print`, or calculations, or explicit formatting, or ...

As mentioned many people have misunderstandings about numbers. As such, a question *about* or *containing* misunderstandings is not bad per se. But it must clearly define these misunderstandings – either directly by mentioning them or indirectly by the requirements – to be generally *useful*.